# Manipulate content style in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

In cytoscape.js I can style nodes with

```
style: [
  {
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
      'content': 'data(id)',
    }
  },
```

When I change the content to `'content': 'data(id), data(id)'`, it just interprets it as a string.

Is it possible to handle the variables as variables instead of just a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function:

```
content: function( ele ){ return 'foo' + ele.data('bar') + 'baz'; }
```

http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers

Comment: Is it also possible to disable html escaping?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can't put HTML in a label.

Comment: Oh okay. Thought I could use KaTeX or MathJax in the labels

Comment: You use MathJax as background images, not labels -- because MathJax doesn't/can't/shouldn't output plain text.  Just make sure to use SVG output with MathJax.  Maybe turn off background clipping in your stylesheet if formulas are long.

Comment: What do you mean? KaTeX produces an html string that is converted to look like math formulas using javascript and css, but since html is disabled, all the tags (`<span class="...", id="...">`, etc.) are escaped and thus just shown as html instead of rendered html.

Comment: MathJax can output SVG from TeX input.  Don't bother with KaTeX -- it's useful for putting a formula in a paragraph, not in a visualisation.